# How can I connect my Ml built"python"to my JS?

Tags: javascript, python, html, tensorflow, prediction

```js
const predictionForm = document.getElementById("predictionForm");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const amount = document.querySelectorAll("span");
let welcomeName = document.getElementById("name");
const prophesyBtn = document.getElementById("prophesyCost");
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';


predictionForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  resultVisibility();
  handleFormSubmit(event);
});

//display the name of the user
let currName = "setah";
welcomeName.innerText = currName;

//display the amount
currAmount = "10,459";
amount.forEach((el) => (el.innerText = currAmount));

// the prediction result visibility
function resultVisibility() {
  result.style.display = "flex";
  prophesyBtn.style.display = "none";
}

function handleFormSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission


  // Access form data using FormData object
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  for (const [key, value] of formData?.entries()) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
  //Prediction capture
  async function loadModel() {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('C:\Users\HUAWEI\OneDrive\Desktop\Medical-Insurance-main\Medical-Insurance-main\model\model.json');  // Replace with path
    return model;
}
async function predictCost(children, age, sex, bmi,region) {
  // Preprocess data 
  const data = tf.tensor([children,age, sex, bmi,region]); // Assuming numerical inputs

  const prediction = model.predict(data);
  const cost = prediction.dataSync()[0];  // Extract the predicted cost
  document.getElementById('prophesy_cost').textContent = `prophesy Cost: $${cost.toFixed(2)}`;
  return cost;
}
//display the name of the user
let currName = "setah";
welcomeName.innerText = currName;

//display the amount
currAmount = "10,459";
amount.forEach((el) => (el.innerText = currAmount));

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sorts+Mill+Goudy:ital@0;1&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Almarai:wght@300;400;700;800&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="/about.html">About</a>
        <a href="./contact.html">Contact</a>
        <a class="active">Start Prediction</a>
      </nav>
      <a href="/index.html">
        <img src="/images/untitledh-removebg-preview-2.png" alt="" />
      </a>
    </header>
    <div>
      <h2 class="welcome">
        Welcome
        <p id="name"></p>
      </h2>
      <div class="prediction">
        <form id="predictionForm">
          <div>
            <div>
              <label class="red" for="age">Age</label>
              <input required type="date" id="age" name="age" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="red" for="children">Children</label>
              <input required id="children" type="number" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <label class="red" for="Bmi">Bmi</label>
              <input required type="number" id="Bmi" name="Bmi" />
            </div>

            <div>
              <label class="red" for="region">Region</label>

              <select required name="region" id="region">
                <option disabled selected value="">Select your region</option>
                <option value="1:Southwest">1:Southwest</option>
                <option value="2:Southeast">2:Southeast</option>
                <option value="3:Northwest">3:Northwest</option>
                <option value="4:Northeast">4:Northeast</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <div>
              <label class="red">Smoker</label>
              <div>
                <div class="smokerOption">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    id="smokerYes"
                    name="smoker"
                    value="1:yes"
                  />
                  <label for="smokerYes">Yes</label><br />
                </div>
                <div class="smokerOption">
                  <input
                    required
                    type="radio"
                    id="smokerNo"
                    name="smoker"
                    value="0:no"
                  />
                  <label for="smokerNo">No</label><br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label class="red">Sex</label>
              <div>
                <div class="sexOption">
                  <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="1: Female" />
                  <label for="famale">female</label><br />
                </div>
                <div class="sexOption">
                  <input
                    required
                    type="radio"
                    id="male"
                    name="sex"
                    value="0: Male"
                  />
                  <label for="male">male</label><br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button id="prophesyCost" type="submit">Prophesy</button>
          <br>
    <span id="prophesy_cost"></span>
        </form>
        <section id="result" class="result"> /* popup class */
          <hr />
          <p>Your expected insurance amount</p>
          <div class="amount">
            <img src="/images/green cir.svg" alt="" />
            <h2><span>0</span> SAR</h2>
          </div>

          <div>
            <p>Total Paid</p>
            <p class="num"><span></span> SAR</p>
          </div>

          <a href="/index.html">
            <button  class="small">Home</button>
          </a>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./prediction.js"></script>
</html>
```

I built my ML in Python, and I need to integrate it into my website, "HTML, CSS, and JS.", I use @tensorflow.tfjs in my prediction. Js page, and I added the path of the ML file, but it is not working. I tried several ways, but all of them are not working. Anyone can help me, please! My website is a prediction of medical insurance costs. I want help. How can I integrate them?

Comment: "I tried several ways, but all of them are not working." ... Not seeing any code in your question.

Comment: i add mu JS and HTML code